# How to get long JSON response divided in modules for showing in ListView or RecyclerView depending upon screen visible?

Tags: java, php, android, json, database

Rather than describing from zero to all, I would like to illustrate the thing I wanted with an example.

Let's take an example of `Playstore`, when we search for any application, we get a long list of search results. Only those results are downloaded first which we can see first depends upon screen size not all results are downloaded at once. How to make that kind of request-response cycle in my application.

I use PHP for back-end to get results in `JSON` format. So, how to get `JSON` response in modular form.

Comment: you can use pagination for this.

Comment: After your comment, I went through some blogs, now I want to ask that do I have to implement back-end in such a way that client is sending information such that how many `JSON` items server should send to client at a time and the request goes on again and again ?

Comment: yes use that method.

Comment: Ohk thanks buddy! Best of luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the concept of PAGINATION on your backend and send your response and use the concept of LAZY LOADING on your RecyclerView

Here i have added code for setting lazy loading in recyclerview

```
mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
            super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

            if (mLayoutManager.findLastCompletelyVisibleItemPosition() ==
                    mObjectList.size() - 1 && !mIsLoading && !mIsEnded) {
                mIsLoading = true;
                getList();
            }
        }
    });


private void getList() {
    addProgressItem();
    JsonObjectRequest jsonObjectRequest = new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.GET,
            mUrl, null, new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
            mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            removeProgressItem();
            setLoading(); // isLoading = false
            handleListResponse(response);
            isEmptyList();
        }
    }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            mRefreshLayout.setRefreshing(false);
            removeProgressItem();
            setLoading();
            VolleyErrorHandler.handle(MainActivity.this, error);
            isEmptyList();
        }
    });

    AppController.getInstance().addToRequestQueue(jsonObjectRequest, "list");
}

private void handleListResponse(JSONObject response) {
    clearList();

    try {
        mCount = response.getInt("count");
        mNextUrl = response.getString("next_url");

        //process JSON here

        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        if (mNextUrl == null || TextUtils.isEmpty(mNextUrl) || mNextUrl.equals("null")) {
            isEnded();//set list ended
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

private void addProgressItem() {
    if (mCount != 0) {
        mObjectList.add(null);
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(mObjectList.size() - 1);
    }
}

private void removeProgressItem() {
    if (mCount != 0) {
        mObjectList.remove(mObjectList.size() - 1);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(mObjectList.size());
    }
}

private void setLoading() {
    mIsLoading = false;
}

private void isEnded() {
    mIsEnded = true;
}

private void isEmptyList() {
    if (mObjectList.size() == 1) {
        mObjectList.add(1, -1);
        mAdapter.notifyItemInserted(1);
    } else if (mObjectList.get(1) instanceof Integer) {
        mObjectList.remove(1);
        mAdapter.notifyItemRemoved(1);
    }
}
```